# a strange $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, callback

I have this code, a simple jQuery GET:

```
    $.get(url, params, function(){
      function_call()
    })
```

I wonder why the `function_call()` is never executed. The server at `url` is up and running and changing the function to `$.ajax()` shows no errors (the `error` option is not executed), but it's not working.

Any clue? `params` is a simple JS object of two fields, and of course I've used `$.get()` thousands of times with no problems.

Comment: Run Firebug or Fiddler and make sure that the server is replying.

Comment: I believe you can't make ajax requests across domains. I think there are a few plugins or other methods that let you get around that however.

Comment: **anomareh** almost certainly has it; are you running into an issue with the Same Origin Policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've given (and the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype)), it should be working. Are you absolutely sure you're actually calling it (the `$.get`)? Can you create a minimal, self-contained example of the problem? (That does two things: 1. It usually helps you solve the problem yourself, because you figure it out in the process; 2. It gives us more to work with. :-) )

Alternately, **anomareh** mentioned (in a comment) the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which you might be running into.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks good.  When something like this doesn't work for me, it's because I have a silly mistake at some other point, like a syntax error in the callback function or formulating the URL etc.

We would need to see a little more of your process to help more.  Try making you're callback function **only** do a simple alert.  Have an alert right before the $.get() is called, ideally spouting the URL.  If you control the server functionality, put a breakpoint there (or whatever you need to do) to make sure the call is getting there.  Switch back to $.ajax() and see if you get the error callback function called if you switch the URL to something bogus.

I guess I make so many dumb mistakes with my javascript/jquery, that I'm good with debugging ideas.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a semicolon after `function_call()`?

The only other thing I would try is `$.get(url, params, function_call)` --- this will work only if your function call has no params -- take note that `function_call` intentionally does not have `()` after it.